# BCL Interfaces and beforefieldinit flag

Tags: c#, interface

I wrote a programm which scans BCL types and checks beforefieldinit flag. So some interfaces have not beforefieldinit flag (ICollection, IEnumerable) and some have it. 
Does somebody known why? What for?

Comment: Does `beforefieldinit` have any effect on interfaces at all?

Comment: I dont known. It's interesting too... As I know it's possible to define a type constructor for an interface, but it's dosn't supported by C# (in IL and managed C++ only).

Comment: to be clear... where/how are you looking to see the beforefieldinit flag?

Comment: These interfaces don't have beforefieldinit.  You'd better check your code.

Comment: Which interfaces have the beforefieldinit flag? Clarify it

Comment: System.Collections.ICollectionContract, IEnumerableContract etc. But it's not interfaces... my fault...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say:

> So some interfaces have beforefieldinit flag (ICollection, IEnumerable)

Neither reflector nor ildasm show this...

for example (via ildasm):

```
.class interface public abstract auto ansi System.Collections.IEnumerable
{
  .custom instance void System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute::.ctor(bool) = ( 01 00 01 00 00 ) 
  .custom instance void System.Runtime.InteropServices.GuidAttribute::.ctor(string) = ( 01 00 24 34 39 36 42 30 41 42 45 2D 43 44 45 45   // ..$496B0ABE-CDEE
                                                                                        2D 31 31 64 33 2D 38 38 45 38 2D 30 30 39 30 32   // -11d3-88E8-00902
                                                                                        37 35 34 43 34 33 41 00 00 )                      // 754C43A..
} // end of class System.Collections.IEnumerable

.class interface public abstract auto ansi System.Collections.ICollection
       implements System.Collections.IEnumerable
{
  .custom instance void System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute::.ctor(bool) = ( 01 00 01 00 00 ) 
} // end of class System.Collections.ICollection

.class interface public abstract auto ansi System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<+ T>
       implements System.Collections.IEnumerable
{
  .custom instance void System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TypeDependencyAttribute::.ctor(string) = ( 01 00 14 53 79 73 74 65 6D 2E 53 5A 41 72 72 61   // ...System.SZArra
                                                                                                   79 48 65 6C 70 65 72 00 00 )                      // yHelper..
} // end of class System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1

.class interface public abstract auto ansi System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1<T>
       implements class System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!T>,
                  System.Collections.IEnumerable
{
  .custom instance void System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TypeDependencyAttribute::.ctor(string) = ( 01 00 14 53 79 73 74 65 6D 2E 53 5A 41 72 72 61   // ...System.SZArra
                                                                                                   79 48 65 6C 70 65 72 00 00 )                      // yHelper..
} // end of class System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1
```

contrast to `Comparer` that *does* have this flag:

```
.class public auto ansi serializable sealed beforefieldinit System.Collections.Comparer
       extends System.Object
       implements System.Collections.IComparer,
                  System.Runtime.Serialization.ISerializable
{
  .custom instance void System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute::.ctor(bool) = ( 01 00 01 00 00 ) 
} // end of class System.Collections.Comparer
```

I *suspect* this is simply a false-positive in your program.

Comment: Huh! It's seems that I mistaken... Thank everybody for answers, I appologies...
Check my programm again - now I don't have access to it.

Comment: Ok. Now I see that it's not interface types: System.Collections.ICollectionContract, IEnumerableContract etc. Never use it before.

Comment: @Smeliy That's why I prefer calling my contract classes `ContractForIEnumerable`. I think the `I` prefix for classes is very confusing. These classes are not for direct use, but will be used automatically if you use code contracts where they define the contract of an interface.